# IO Scanner Java

Tags: java, input, io

I want to get the user input of 5 numbers then change that input into integers by splitting the string. But I keep on getting the error which says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "". Any clues on how to fix it?

```
public class Exercise{
 public static void main(String [] args){

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input Quizzes: ");
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String quiz = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part = quiz.split(" ");
        int pq1 = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
        int pq2 = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
  System.out.println("Input Additionals: ");
  String quiz1 = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part1 = quiz1.split(" ");
        int pqa1 = Integer.parseInt(part1[0]);
        int pqa2 = Integer.parseInt(part1[1]);
  System.out.println("Input Recitation: ");
        int recitation = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Input Seatworks: ");
        int swhw1 = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Input Exercises ");
  String exp = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part2 = exp.split(" ");
            int ex1 = Integer.parseInt(part2[0]),
                ex2 = Integer.parseInt(part2[1]),
                ex3 = Integer.parseInt(part2[2]),
                ex4 = Integer.parseInt(part2[3]),
                ex5 = Integer.parseInt(part2[4]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: how do you enter numbers? `1 2 3 4 5` then hit Enter? your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Not sure of what the input it is, but have you trimmed your strings? Use the trim() method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem may cause in 2 situations:

1. the string contains other char that they not digits
2. you have more than one space between the numbers and therefore you
   get more then 5 cell in the split array (those cells contain the
   empty string "")

so.. add this line before you split command:

`exp = exp.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");`

this will fix the problem! and `try&catch` are also recommended

this is the full code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
System.out.println("Input Exercises ");  
String exp = scan.nextLine();  
exp = exp.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");  
String [] part2 = exp.split(" ");  
        int ex1 = Integer.parseInt(part2[0]),  
            ex2 = Integer.parseInt(part2[1]),  
            ex3 = Integer.parseInt(part2[2]),  
            ex4 = Integer.parseInt(part2[3]),  
            ex5 = Integer.parseInt(part2[4]);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the nextInt that it was used.

I recommend first use nextLine() to read the entire line and then Use Integer.parseInt() method to validate the integer input.

Like this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); String s = scan.nextLine();

try{
    Integer.parseInt(s); } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Its not a valid Integer"); }
```

Or you can just put a next line before the scanner (This is not recommended)

```
public static void main(String [] args){

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Input Quizzes: ");
  scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String quiz = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part = quiz.split(" ");
        int pq1 = Integer.parseInt(part[0]);
        int pq2 = Integer.parseInt(part[1]);
  System.out.println("Input Additionals: ");
  String quiz1 = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part1 = quiz1.split(" ");
        int pqa1 = Integer.parseInt(part1[0]);
        int pqa2 = Integer.parseInt(part1[1]);
  System.out.println("Input Recitation: ");
        int recitation = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Input Seatworks: ");
        int swhw1 = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
  System.out.println("Input Exercises ");
  String exp = scan.nextLine();
  String [] part2 = exp.split(" ");
            int ex1 = Integer.parseInt(part2[0]),
                ex2 = Integer.parseInt(part2[1]),
                ex3 = Integer.parseInt(part2[2]),
                ex4 = Integer.parseInt(part2[3]),
                ex5 = Integer.parseInt(part2[4]);
  }
```